# Cannot run couchDB msi installer from Inno Setup

Tags: couchdb, inno-setup

I have some software I install for my company. The software works fine, but it needs to connect to CouchDB to actually function.

So I am trying to make an installer that installs .NET 3.5, then installs CouchDB, then installs my software as a single process,

I always end up with the same error

> Unable to execute file:
> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-P0C5V.tmp\CouchDBInstaller.msi
>
> CreateProcess failed; code 2.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I've  tested  my CouchDB installer, it works. I've tried across multiple workstations, and different install locations. I've reordered the Inno Setup install processes so it's .NET, then CouchDB, then electron. I've added the credentials for CouchDB. I was hoping to silently install CouchDB in the background.

Comment: As Martin said: An MSI file is not an executable binary; it is a Windows installer database file. Use `msiexec.exe` with the `/i` parameter to tell Windows installer to install it. You will also probably need the `/qb` or `/qb-` parameters. See the `msiexec` docs for details on available options.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to run .msi, as if it was an executable binary. It is not.

- If you do it via `[Run]` section, use [`shellexec` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=shellexec) to allow running everything that shell can "run", even if it is not a binary.
- If you do it via `Exec` function, use [`ShellExec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec) instead.
- Or run [`msiexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec) explicitly to install the MSI.